# Not able to create a Zip archive in Gradle

Tags: zip, gradle

I'm trying to create a simple Zip archive that contains all the javascript files in my resources directory

Here's the code:

```
  task zip(type:Zip){
    from ('resources/'){
        include '*.js'
    }
    into 'resources'
}
```

This does not seem to work for some reason. I've heard many people saying that all you need is a `from` and `into` to create an archive. Can someone help me here ? I'm using Gradle v1.0. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try something like this ([docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:)):

```
task zip(type:Zip) {
 from ('resources/')
 include '*.js'
 into 'resources' // note that this specifies path *in* the archive
 destinationDir file('dir') // directory that you want your archive to be placed in
}
```

Comment: Using Gradle 1.10 on Windows, I got an error when I gave destinationDir a string, but it seems to work fine when I give it a File, like `destinationDir(file("target"))`

Comment: destinationDir setter does take a file

Answer (score 10):

```
task someTask << {

    // other code...

    task(zipResources, type: Zip) {
        destinationDir new File(projectDir, 'resources')
        archiveName 'resources.zip'
        from 'src/main/webapp'
        include '*.js'
    }.execute()

    task(zipSomethingElse, type: Zip) {
        destinationDir buildDir
        archiveName 'source-code.zip'
        from 'src/main/java'
        include '**/*.java'
    }.execute()

    // some other code...

}
```