# Make Zip task run after dependencies are resolved

Tags: java, gradle

I have a subproject B that depends on other subproject A. I have included subproject A in "build.gradle" of subproject B.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projA')
}
```

Both of my sub-projects A and B create a bundled zip upon a release. I want to copy some files belonging to subproject A to subproject B without referencing subproject A again. The root project's "build.gradle" script contains the following task.

```
subprojects {
    task bundleBin(type: Zip) {
        description 'Creates "bin.zip" bundle.'

        dependsOn build

        def bundleName = "$outputName-bin"

        /// THIS DOES NOT WORK
        def deps = configurations.runtime.getAllDependencies().findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }
        println "GROOT: " + deps

        into("$bundleName/dep") {
            /// THE LINE BELOW WORKS
            /// I do not want a fixed reference since it is already defined in each subproject's "build.gradle" file
            //from project(':projA').file('conf/')
            for (dep in deps) {
                def proj = dep.getDependencyProject()
                from (proj.projectDir) {
                    include "conf/"
                    include "scripts/"
                }
            }
        }

        into(bundleName) {
            from(".") {
                include "conf/"
                include "scripts/"
            }
        }

        into("$bundleName/lib") {
            from configurations.runtime.allArtifacts.files
            from configurations.runtime
        }

        archiveName = "${bundleName}.zip"
    }
}
```

The reason why I do not want to reference subproject A again is because I have a list of projects that depend on some other projects and I do not want to maintain each dependency individually.

What I want the above script to do is, when running for B takes "conf/" and "scripts/" in A and B, and puts them in "B-bin.zip". Whereas, if I have a subproject C that have a dependency on A and B, the above script will take "conf/" and "scripts/" in A, B and C, and puts them in "C-bin.zip".

When I run the above script, the dependencies do not appear unless I encapsulate it in "doLast". However, this does not work in the Zip task.

My question is, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alpar, this is due to the Zip task processing the dependencies during the configuration phase. To resolve it, I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364046/171215).

Thus, my bundle code now looks like:

```
task bundleBin << {
    task bundleBin_childTask(type: Zip) {
        def bundleName = "$outputName-bin"
        def deps = configurations.runtime.getAllDependencies().findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }

        into(bundleName) {
            for (dep in deps) {
                def proj = dep.getDependencyProject()
                from (proj.projectDir) {
                    include "conf/"
                    include "scripts/"
                }
            }
        }

        into(bundleName) {
            from(".") {
                include "conf/"
                include "scripts/"
            }
        }

        into("$bundleName/lib") {
            from configurations.runtime.allArtifacts.files
            from configurations.runtime
        }

        archiveName = "${bundleName}.zip"
    }

    bundleBin_childTask.execute()
}
```

This solution forces the Zip task resolve its included files in the execution phase.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to resolve the configuration first.
You could do that by using [.resolvedConfiguration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html)  but note that resolving at configuration time means that this will be done regardless of what task is called, and should be avoided. 
[This anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048841/gradle-task-with-a-custom-dependency-configuration) suggest you can achieve the same by iterating directly over the configuration.

You could use  [gradle.taskGraph.whenReady](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#configure-by-dag) to delay resolving the configuration only if your task is about to be executed. You can still configure your task there.